# Typescript : pass a method as a parameter of another method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Within my **angular** app I have this treatment :

```
this.myServiceOne.getDataOne().subscribe((res => {this.variableOne= res}));
this.myServiceTwo.getDataTwo().subscribe((res => {this.variableTwo= res}));
this.myServiceThree.getDataThree().subscribe((res => {this.variableThree= res}));
this.myServiceFour.getDataFour().subscribe((res => {this.variableFour= res}));
```

My purpose is to make a generic function in this way:

```
  loadData(myVariable, myserviceMethod){
    serviceMethod().subscribe((res => {pefVar = res}));
  }
```

and replace my treatment like this :

```
this.loadData(this.variableOne, this.myServiceOne.getDataOne);
```

But this seems to not work and it can't understand this injection : **(this.myServiceOne.getDataOne)**

**Your suggestions ?**

Comment: By defining a generic function, are you trying to find a clean way to deal with the initial treatment? Would you accept an usual rxjs best practice to achieve it?

Comment: @YuchaoWu i'm trying to make it almost generic

Comment: What doesn't work and what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

To delegate the setting of the local variable, you'll either have to pass in some kind of callback (much like you currently do in your `subscribe`), or the name of the property you want to update.

You're really not saving much effort by making it generic, unless there is some amount of repeated code, which there isn't in your example.

If you **really** wanted to write a generic function, you could take these approaches as a starting point:

**Callback**

The type of the object returned from the observable is generic. Tee callback accepts a single argument of that same type.

```js
loadData<T>(serviceMethod: Observable<T>, action: (value: T) => void) {
  serviceMethod.subscribe((res: T) => action(res));
}
```

Which you would invoke like this:

```js
this.loadData(this.myServiceOne.getDataOne(), res => this.variableOne = res);
```

**Property name**

`TKey` must be a named key on `AppComponent`.

`TValue` is the type of that named key and the type of the object returned from the observable.

```js
loadData2<TKey extends keyof AppComponent, TValue extends AppComponent[TKey]>(    
  serviceMethod: Observable<TValue>, 
  key: TKey
): void {
  const component: AppComponent = this;
  serviceMethod.subscribe((res: TValue) => {      
    component[key] = res;
  });
}
```

Which you would invoke like this:

```js
this.loadData(this.myServiceOne.getDataOne(), 'variableOne');
```

**Property name (fully generic)**

`T` is the type of the component.

`TKey` must be a named key on `T`.

`TValue` is the type of that named key and the type of the object returned from the observable.

```js
loadData2<T, TKey extends keyof T, TValue extends T[TKey]>(    
  component: T,
  serviceMethod: Observable<TValue>, 
  key: TKey
): void {
  serviceMethod.subscribe((res: TValue) => {      
    component[key] = res;
  });
}
```

Which you would invoke like this:

```js
this.loadData(this, this.myServiceOne.getDataOne(), 'variableOne');
```

**Promises**

You could also convert the observable to a promise and use async / await, but I really don't see the point of doing this.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btfqng

Comment: It is also possible to pass member key (e.g. `res => this[key] = res`), then callback is not needed

Comment: True, as long as you constrain the key to ensure it is a member of the component, otherwise you lose the type safety.